# JavaScript non-persistent security question

Tags: javascript, security

Despite my paranoia I've never really gotten around to understanding web security more, so my lack of knowledge is causing me a bit of confusion for this.

Example: Let's say you have 2 text boxes, both are for user input.

The user types in whatever they want into those two text boxes and clicks a button, the button then uses a bit of JavaScript and concatenates whatever is in those two text boxes and displays it out in a div.

My question is, in this case, since it's using JavaScript client side, do you need to really sanitize user input?

What if it outputted to a text box instead of a div? Or as an alert?

I understand that when it comes to forms/PHP you always want to sanitize input, but I'm not really familiar with JavaScript security precautions.

It's my understanding that since this is client-side, and no data is being saved by the server, that whatever the user does (tries to throw in some malicious code or whatnot) won't affect anyone but that user, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not a security issue.  The reason why is because an attacker has to force a victim's the browser into making this action in order for it to be XSS.

However, if you grab input from something like `document.location` and then print it to the page using `document.write()` then this is [DOM based XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).  But this is very a uncommon form of XSS.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much, just wanted to make sure there wasn't some crazy way for it to end up a security risk.

Comment: @Archonix security is a very difficult computational problem.  There are some very smart people on SO,  but make sure to test your security systems and do your own research.  I have seen some terribly insecure answers accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to sanitize anything that is not going to the server.

If people want to do something to their instance of your page, the only one they can hurt is themselves. Look at everything you can do with an extension like GreaseMonkey ... we're talking a lot more than just concatenating strings and displaying them.